# Why does number to copy keep changing?

Tags: macos, download

So I’m currently copying some fairly large files from a network drive to my local hard disk drive.

I’m using an early 2011 15” MacBook Pro with Mac OS X 10.10.5 (Yosemite) installed. In the attached picture, the number of files the OS thinks it needs to copy keeps changing (ranging from the mid-3,000 to upwards of 5,000).

It’s fairly obvious that the number decreases with time, but at the beginning the count was pretty volatile, moving up and down until about 25% through the download.

[image: Down from 5,000]

Comment: I'm assuming it's because the OS was finding more files in the directory as it was copying.

Comment: @Austin, my thoughts as well, but that sort of begs the question: did the OS not traverse the directory tree before beginning the copy operation? With a 2.2 GHz quad core CPU, the time penalty must be bordering on insignificant?

Comment: I doubt traversing the directory has to do with the CPU speed. I would assume it's almost all disk read speed. And I couldn't say for sure that OSX looks at the whole directory before copying or not.

Answer (score 0):

> So I’m currently copying some fairly large files from a network drive
>   to my local hard disk drive.

The issue is you are copying files from a network drive to a local drive. And your local system does not have easy access to the filesystem information stored in the inode table on the remote network drive. So what is happening is the “Finder” is constantly updating the calculations as it traverses more directories/files on the remote network drive.

In contrast if you were to do a *reverse* version of the operation—by copying files from your local file system to the remote network volume—the reported amount of files would be calculated faster and more accurately. The reason is that the “Finder” would not only have faster I/O access to the local drives but—most importantly—the “Finder” would also have direct access local filesystem’s inode table.

By having direct access to the inode table, the “Finder” essentially has access to a filesystem data index/table-of-contents that will tell it pretty much instantaneously how big a file/directory is without even touching the file.

Without direct access to the inode table on a local drive, the “Finder” is making calculations as it traverses remote directories. So it makes for a tad of a frustrating experience if you are dealing with thousands of files and different directory structures.

Slight tangent, but I have found the “Finder” to be sluggish dealing with network copies like this. So I prefer to use [Carbon Copy Cloner](https://bombich.com) when dealing with network copies like this. The software uses [`rsync`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/rsync.1.html) in it’s core, but the GUI makes it easier to manage and understand for casual users. Is the file count estimate better? Not really. But I do find Carbon Copy Cloner/`rsync` to be more efficient and nice to use for incremental backups.